# How to evaluate results of PoseNet from TensorFlow Lite

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite, pose-detection

I am using PoseNet from TensorFlow Lite library to detect key point on images. What is the best way to evaluate the results. I feed in images and get key points as a result. How can I say if the result is good, bad or average?

Answer (score 0):

From the output, you can extract the confidence score for each point, between `0.0` and `1.0`. You can then determine whether the average confidence score is greater than a set threshold (e.g., `0.5`) to tell whether the result is good or bad.

Please see the example apps to learn how the confidence score can be obtained.

Android example: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/posenet/android/posenet/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/posenet/lib/Posenet.kt#L259

iOS example: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/posenet/ios/PoseNet/ModelDataHandler/ModelDataHandler.swift#L229

Comment: It's still detecting the keypoints incorrectly after I set a threshold of the confidence score. I wanted a mechanism where I could test the quality towards the end when I already have the results from PoseNet.